# Loading class in regualr php file in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project and in it, I create a regular (`.php`) file that I am posting some data to. In that file, I want to use a class that I installed using composer in the Laravel project. When I post data to the page I am getting the error `No such file in directory` and `require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php`. How can I resolve this my project is almost complete if I can get this working.

I've tried: require "class name" but the same error.

PHP file posting to:

```
<?php
    require "vendor/autoload.php";

    require 'vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Builder.php';
    require 'vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer.php';

    //I've tried using these require statements

    use \vendor\Lcobucci\JWT\Builder; 
    use \vendor\Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;

    someFunctiion(){
        // do stuff with function from class
    }
?>
```

I expect that when I post to this page, the function from the class I am 'using' will be called but instead, it's saying `require()` failed to open class.

Comment: Where is located the script you posted in your project folder? Also, do not hesitate to take a look at the documentation for [`Lcobucci\JWT`](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.3/README.md), you will see that you are misusing the library (you should use `use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;` to import the Builder class).

Comment: The script i am posting to is located in C:\xampp\htdocs\laraproj\resources\views\webPost.php and I am posting from C:\xampp\htdocs\laraproj\resources\views\testing.blade.php

Comment: So you see your vendor path is not correct because there is not `vendor` folder inside `/resources/views/`. Try to change it to `require __DIR__ . "/../../vendor/autoload.php;`. Do not forget to fix your use statements as well ;).

Comment: THANKN YOU so much. However, I am looking at the documentation and I don't see what you mean by I am using the Library incorrectly, do you mind explaining?

Comment: You can omit the 2 last require statement because you are using the autoloader. Then, you can also omit the `\vendor\` before your two use statements because the autoloader will find the source for you ;)

Comment: Ok my friend thanks again.